# Is the meta tag required on all pages

Tags: html, seo, meta

Is the

```
<meta name="description" content="description here">
<meta name="keywords" content="word, word1, word2, word3">
```

required on all pages or just the index of the website? I know this doesn't have much influence on SEO, but it does add a bit.

Also, what other things can be done to improve SEO on a just recently started website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2):

Meta tags are informations related to the page on which this tags are deployed.

So, having this tags on your home is not enough. **Every single HTML document should have this informations** and like a `<title>` **they have to be different**.

- The description must describe the page (not the website).
- The keywords must be the relevant keywords of the page (not the website).

Answer (score 0):

Not required but yes helps search engomes know what you're about. You should always have site map of your site, search engines use that.

Comment: are there any automated tools to make sitemaps?